# Is there a cross-platform solution in C++ for creating an unique process?

Tags: c++, cross-platform

I need to make my program only one process on several platforms. I have known it can be solved with mutex on Windows, but I don't know how are other plat-forms like Linux. Mutex is not a part of C++ 03 standard though it is in C++ 0x standard. I have to wait a long time before compilers support C++ 0x well. Can boost's mutex be used for this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: mutexes are for threads, not processes

Comment: Please clarify: do you mean that if the user tries to execute your application multiple times, there will only be a single process?

Comment: @yi_H Windows Mutexs can span processes.

Comment: @yi_H well, that is not entirely or universally true. At least on Windows a mutex (talking about the actual kernel object, not some wrapped abstraction) can be shared between processes.

Comment: Are you talking about having only one instance of your program running at one time, or having a unique process within your program or perhaps multiple versions of your program running simultaneously?

Comment: @yi_H, a named mutex is global under Windows, so it can be used to synchronize processes, not just threads.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, yes, I mean that.

Comment: @arunkumar, you're right except I only need one instance even there're multiple versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at boost's interprocess library:  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/interprocess.html
I have used a named_mutex http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/named_mutex.html to make sure only one instance of my program was running.

Answer (score 4):

Neither std::mutex nor boost::mutex expose the functionality of Win32 mutexes that is needed to make this work, namely system-global named mutexes, so no, you can't use either of them.

The easiest and most portable way is probably to simply create a lock file (you can write a PID to it, and then check if the process still exists to avoid locking the program out after abnormal termination). You still might need some platform-specific glue code, though.

Comment: I have little experience in C++, but wouldn't opening a agreed-upon high port be possible as well? It would have the advantage of having guaranteed cleanup when your application quits for any reason and being able to communicate with the other instance, if necessary.

Comment: @Cat Plus Plus, I don't think it's a good idea to create a lock file. In this case, I have to consider how to process exceptions about files. That's a heavy burden. But thank you all the same :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe this can be done with a boost::mutex, but you can probably achieve the desired effect with the [Boost Interprocess library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/interprocess.html).